# Does an angular.forEach create it's own scope?

Tags: angularjs

My code has this HTML snippet:

```
<div ng-repeat="wf in wos.word.wordForms">
     {{ wf }}
     <textarea ng-change="wf.statusId = 2"
               ng-model="wf.definition">
     </textarea>
     ...
```

In a service I have this:

```
wordFormCheckAndUpdate = (): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var self = this;
    var promises = [];
    angular.forEach(self.word.wordForms, function (wf, key) {
        if (wf.statusId == Status.Dirty) {
            if (wf.createdDate) {
                var updatePromise = self.wordFormUpdateSubmit(wf);
                promises.push(updatePromise);
            } else {
                var addPromise = self.wordFormAddSubmit(wf);
                promises.push(addPromise);
            }
        }          
    });
    return self.$q.all(promises);
};
```

wordFormAddSubmit and wordFormUpdateSubmit modify the data in wf:

```
wf = angular.copy(response.data);
wf.statusId = 3;
wf.abc = "test"
```

When one of these functions is called it does not seem to change what is displayed above the textarea and the statusId still shows as 2 and "test" does not appear. Does anyone have any ideas what might be happening?

Update. Here are the two functions that are called:

```
wordFormAddSubmit = (wf: IWordForm): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var self = this;
    return self.$http({
        url: self.ac.dataServer + "/api/WordForm/Post",
        method: "POST",
        data: wf
    })
        .then(
        (response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<IWordForm>): any => {
            wf = angular.copy(response.data);
            self.$timeout(function () {
                wf.statusId = 3;
                wf.sourceId = 999;
            }, 3);


        },
        (error: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>): any => {
            self.ers.error(error);
            return self.$q.reject(error);
        });
}

wordFormUpdateSubmit = (wf: IWordForm): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var self = this;
    return self.$http({
        url: self.ac.dataServer + "/api/WordForm/Put",
        method: "PUT",
        data: wf
    })
        .then(
        (response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<IWordForm>): any => {
            wf = angular.copy(response.data);
            //$timeout(function () {
                wf.statusId = 3;
            //}, 1);
                var a = wf;
                var b = wf;

        },
        (error: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>): any => {
            self.ers.error(error);
            return self.$q.reject(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: I think all that is happening is when you get the response back, you replace the original wf with a different object. But since you don't post your full wordFormAddSubmit and wordFormUpdateSubmit or show where they're being called, that's just a guess.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship - I will post these for you.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't see where these new wf objects are making it into the collection that your ng-repeat is iterating over.

Comment: Doesn't this copy them back into the collection: wf = angular.copy(response.data); ?

Comment: No, it just creates a copy of the data that you can do with what you want. Putting that copy in the collection would look something like `wos.word.wordForms[someIndex] = wf;`